# Trouble making access methods for an array of pointers to classes

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, object

T have problems making access methods for an array of pointers to objects.

```
    class DummyClass
    {
    private:
        class Object
            {
                friend Dummyclass;
            };

        Object* Array[SIZE];

    public:
        void Set (int iii, Object *pointer) { Array[iii] = pointer; };
        Object *& Get (int iii) { return Array[iii]; };

    };
```

This is what the class looks like.
In methods for the DummyClass, I try to acces the pointers as:

```
    Array->Set(0, pointer);
    Object* temporary_pointer = Array->Get(1);
```

Now, this obviously doesn't work, but I'm all burnt out and can't figure out why.
Any help or suggestion appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you want `Object` to be private in `DummyClass`?

Comment: It's a form of a table, where Objects are Elements in the DummyClass.

Comment: You need to be much more specific about "doesn't work".

Answer (score 0):

Given your declaration:

```
    Object* Array[SIZE];
```

`Array` is a plain C array. So you can execute:

```
Array[iii] = pointerToObj;
```

to set its iii-th element (with `0 <= iii < SIZE`).

EDIT:

if you declare an object:

```
  DummyClass dummyObject;
```

then you can do:

```
     dummyObject->Set(0, pointer);
     Object* temporary_pointer = dummyObject->Get(1);
```

Comment: Yes, I actually do that in the method implementation, but I'm trying to access the pointers using methods.

Comment: Of course, thanks a lot! I just realized I'm asking a totally stupid, question. I didn't realize I didn't need class access methods to use private objects. And so my question is redundant. Thanks!